# MVC4 and JqGrid - How to make a tree with a hierarchy already existing in my query result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

All the samples I found are making a second query (or more) for the leafs on the tree.

In my case, I already have a

> List<
>   Entity
>   >

on the parent record for the children linked to this parent.

I could always call the parent then make a query for children, as I see in examples, but I would prefer to avoid duplicating the code already existing in the web service I consume!

So I guess my question is, how should I write the javascript code to make JqGrid happy, as both levels are already contained in the JSon result I send to it?

BTW, there are only 2 levels, parent and childs, not more.

Here is how the data looks like, in C#:

```
[DataContract]
    public class CTreeGroup
    {
        public CTreeGroup(RadGroup group, HashSet<Guid> teamIds, bool userHasAllTeams)
        {
            this.Name = group.Name;
            this.Id = group.Id;
            this.Scope = group.Scope;
            this.IsAutomatic = group.IsAutomatic;
            this.IsNotification = group.IsNotification;
            if (userHasAllTeams)
            {
                this.CanAddRemoveUsers = !group.IsAutomatic;
            }
            else
            {
                this.CanAddRemoveUsers = teamIds.Contains(group.Id);
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name;
        [DataMember]
        public Guid Id;
        [DataMember]
        public RadGroupScope Scope;
        [DataMember]
        public bool IsAutomatic;
        [DataMember]
        public bool IsNotification;
        [DataMember]
        public bool CanAddRemoveUsers;

        [DataMember]
        public List<CTreeUser> Users = new List<CTreeUser>();
    }
```

I have made some progress since I asked, as I realized I had not downloaded modules for Subgrid and Tree! I am not seeing the error I had, but it is still not working. I Get syntax errors. Here is the whole JS code I have now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jqGridTree").jqGrid({
            url: '/Test/GetJqGridGroupsData',
            datatype: 'json',
            myType: 'GET',           
            colModel: [                                          
                { label: 'Name', name: 'Name' }           
            ],
            key: 'Id',
            loadonce: true,
            jsonReader: {
                root: 'Data',
                id: 'id',
                repeatitems: false
            },
            //jsonReader: {subgrid: {repeatitems: false}},

            hoverrows: true,
            rowNum: 50,
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            height: 600,
            subGrid: true,
            subgridtype: 'json',
            subGridUrl: showChildGrid('id','Id'),
            subGridModel: [{
                name: ["Full Name"],
                width: ["100%"],
                align: ["left"],
                params: false
            }],
            pager: $('#jqGridTreePager')
        });
    });

    function showChildGrid(parentRowID, parentRowKey) {
        var childGridID = parentRowID + "_table";
        var childGridURL = '/Test/GetJqGridUsersData?' + parentRowKey;
        $('#' + parentRowID).append('<table id=' + childGridID + '></table>');
        $("#" + childGridID).jqGrid({
            url: childGridID,
            myType: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            page: 1,
            colModel: [{ name: 'FullName' }],
            loadonce: true,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
        });
    }


    $(window).bind('resize', function () {
        var width = $('#jqGridTree_Container').width();
        $('#jqGridTree').setGridWidth(width);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: It's probably more easy if you include an example of JSON data which represent the tree. If I understand you correctly you returns all tree at once and have information about the parents/children encoded in some way. You want to display the information as TreeGrid. All is possible, but it's better to explain all on an example of test data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Oleg. Here is the data structure in C#, it's just passed to JqGrid as Json.

Works perfectly well for "flat" lists, but so far, I can't even display only the parent name.... .

I see the records are being loaded in the grid, but nothing is shown.

Comment: If you have only 2 level Tree then probably it's better use subgrid instead of TreeGrid? Which properties have `CTreeUser`? The same like `CTreeGroup`? Which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering, Oleg.

Yes, there are only 2 levels, and no, CTreeUser andf CTreeGroup do NOT have the same properties, at all. 

I don't mind using a subgrid, but the issue (for me) is the same, how do I do in JqGrid to display CTreeUsers without making a second query to the server?

Comment: Wasnot seeing much with IE, but using Firefox + FireBug, I saw I was bitten by the infamous "Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property."

This being solved, I can now see my JSon data properly in Firebug, but still nothing is displayed.